# Распарсить JSON объект

Tags: php, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Добрый день, решил я поработать с VK API, и столкнулся с проблемой в некоторых незнаниях PHP, к сожалению, годных мануалов не нашел.

Цель моей задачи - получить некоторые данные из полученного JSON массива, к примеру, я подаю GET запрос к API VK:

```
$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get?out=0&offset=0&filtres=0&last_message_id=0&count=10&v=5.34&access_token=".$token."";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
$exited = json_decode($page);
```

Я получаю весь массив, все "ОК", но есть одна проблема, я не понимаю, как из этого массива выбрать данные:

```
$message = ...->items[$i]->body; // Текст сообщения
$user_id = ...->items[$i]->user_id; // ID пользователя
$id = ...->items[$i]->id; // ID
$chat_id = ...->items[$i]->chat_id; // ID Диалога
```

Иначе говоря, мне нужно получить только эти данные, исходя из того, что анализируем последние 10 пришедших в ЛС сообщений (ВКонтакте). Если кто-то поможет, то заранее буду благодарен.

Comment: Доброе утро. $exited = json_decode($page, true);

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Но теперь вопрос. Как нам из массива вытянуть данные, а именно:

$message = ...->items[$i]->body; // Текст сообщения (Например)



Вот пример скрипта, который обращается к API, как вытянуть текст сообщения?

Comment: используйте foreach()

Comment: Огромное спасибо)